# If the solution set of this equation is infinity, determine the $b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$(a+b+2)x + a-b -6 = 0$$

If the solution set of this equation is infinity, determine the $b$.

I've tried making $a+b+2$ equal to $0$.

$$a+b = -2$$

However, I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

If $a+b+2\ne 0$ then we would have exactly one solution: $$ x ={b-a+6\over a+b+2}$$
so $a+b+2=0$, but this now means that we have also $a-b-6=0$...

Comment: so we have two equation. they are $a+b+2=0$ and $a-b-6 = 0$

Comment: How to solve them? I see that $a+b = -2$ and $a-b = 6$. $2a =4$, $a = 2$ If $a = 2$, $b$ should be $-4$, right?

Comment: Yes, I've solved it. However, I don't know when to make them equal to $0$. Was this only for this question?

Comment: So what if we're asked to solve $(x-y +3) . (x+y+7) = 19$? Will we apply the same?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: No, it was an example. I had created it a second ago.

Comment: Can you please delete your comments now.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=1$, then $a=2$. Hence:
$$a+b+2=0 \Rightarrow b=-4.$$